# Selecting information from the same table twice

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a single table I need to pull information from.

```
SELECT [workID], [name], [status], [nextStep] FROM [JM_AccountWorkFlowDetail]
```

`[nextStep]` points to the next step in the chain which if available will match something in `workID`.

The above query will return:

```
workID  name                        status  nextStep
7       Name                        Status     0
9       Garnishment to Court        WWW        7
```

As you can see for `workID` 9 it points to 7 which means `workID` 7 is next on the list.

Is it possible to show the name for `nextStep` rather than the number?

A query that would return the following:

```
workID  name                        status  nextStep
7       Name                        Status     0
9       Garnishment to Court        WWW        Name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

join it with the table itself so you can get the name of the `nextStep` via linking it with `workid`.

```
SELECT  a.workID,
        a.name,
        a.status,
        COALESCE(b.name, CAST(a.nextStep AS VARCHAR(5))) nextStepName
FROM    JM_AccountWorkFlowDetail a
        LEFT JOIN JM_AccountWorkFlowDetail b
            ON a.nextStep = b.workID
```

Comment: Is it easy to make nextStepName say 'No Next Step' when the value is 0?

Comment: `COALESCE(b.name, 'No Next Step')` -- try.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ; with
    cte1 as
    (
        SELECT 

        JM.[workID]
        ,JM.[name]
        ,JM.[status]
        ,(select top 1 name from JM_AccountWorkFlowDetail where nextStep = JM.nextStep) nextStep
        FROM [JM_AccountWorkFlowDetail] JM
    )

    select workid, name, status, case when nextstep=0 then 'no next step' else nextstep end
    from cte1
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it say 'No Next Step' when nextStep = 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.[workID], a.[name], a.[status], b.name as nextstep FROM [JM_AccountWorkFlowDetail] a
right outer join [JM_AccountWorkFlowDetail] b
on b.nextstep=a.nextstep
```